# Cannot run default browser from WIX installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

[From tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/net-and-net/launch-the-internet):

```
<Property Id="BROWSER">
  <RegistrySearch Id='DefaultBrowser' Type='raw' Root='HKCR' Key='http\shell\open\command' />
</Property>

<CustomAction Id='LaunchBrowser' Property='BROWSER' ExeCommand='www.something.com' Return='asyncNoWait' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  ...
  <Custom Action='LaunchBrowser' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

As I can see from installation traces, property BROWSER is calculated correctly:

> Property(S): BROWSER = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet
>   Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome

But browser is not open after installation.

> MSI (s) (88:90) [18:38:30:331]: Doing action: LaunchBrowser MSI (s)
>   (88:90) [18:38:30:331]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText  Action start
>   18:38:30: LaunchBrowser. Action ended 18:38:30: INSTALL. Return value
>   1. Action ended 18:38:30: LaunchBrowser. Return value 1631.
>   ...
>   MSI (c) (64:6C) [18:38:30:409]: Product: WebPrintingService -- Installation completed successfully.

What could be wrong?

Windows 7.
UAC - default.

UPDATE:
As a workaround it is possible to use following code(but I am not sure that it is a good workaround):

```
<Property Id="BROWSER">
  <RegistrySearch Id='DefaultBrowser' Type='raw' Root='HKCR' Key='http\shell\open\command' />
</Property>

<CustomAction Id="LaunchBrowser" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='[BROWSER] "test.html"' Return="check"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='LaunchBrowser' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not made an installer that can run the default browser after installtion but I have made an installer with WiX that launches the installed application. As far as I know, the ExeCommand property must contain the file path to an executable file. It can be either the path on your computer directly or a string property you defined containing the file path. Maybe you can tell the program wich file it should open, wich would be in your case a website.

I hope this helps.